# Load a jar BEFORE a system jar

Tags: java, jar

Is there any way to load a jar file BEFORE a system jar? I have a class that is newer than the one in the java system (1.5) that I am forced to use, but it breaks because java loads it's own first (from rt.jar, to be specific). Is there some way I can force it to load my own jar BEFORE system/rt.jar?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this? Are you trying to override the behavior of a system class? Would it be possible to upgrade instead? Depending on what you're trying to do, you might be able to do something with custom classloaders that load things in a different order.

Comment: In the company, we are forced to 1.5. We want to run jaxp which requires 1.6 or above, but also comes with a jar that contains a different version of some classes and want to use those so it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the (JVM specific) startup option `-Xbootclasspath:/p`. This will prepend the supplied list of paths and archives *before* the existing boot classpath, forcing any classes found to be loaded first.

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:<pathtooverridejarhere> mypackage.MyClass
```

Note that:

- It is against Oracles TOS to *distribute* modified JDK classes
- Loading a newer version of a JDK class may still fail, due to
  dependency resolution issues.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the ext or endorsed classpath.

Comment: Classes in the ext folder do not get loaded before system jars.

Comment: That's why I wrote __might__.